# If - else statement without else

Tags: c#, if-statement

Could someone explain me why the if - else statement works like this and not throw an error or exeption? also if this is intentional in C# could someone explain if there is a diffrence between the 2?

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1) { }
    {
            //code
    }
```

rather then using

```
  if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1) { }
  else {
            //code
       }
```

Since I noticed I accidentally made a if - else statement like the above one in my code after I re-arranged the code to make it more readable.

Comment: The first if-statement is empty. `//code` will always be executed.

Comment: you mean that it works because the first { } has noting in it and therefor just gets skipped?

Comment: @maam27 No, it works because the `{ }` under the `if` statement is completely unrelated to the `if` statement. (It's not an if-else statement - it's an if statement followed by a block of code).

Comment: I suppose that the question itself isn't really correct then since its not related to if - else at all then. but I gues I did learn something so it's not completely for nothing, so thanks to all of you who took the time to awnser this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second block in

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1) 
{ 
    var a = 10;
}
{
    var b = 10;
}
```

...is not the else block but just a code block. Here the variable `b`'s scope is only within the block. It is the same as

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1) 
{ 
    var a = 10;
}
var b = 10;
```

... except that the scope for the variable `b` has changed.

Comment: I didn't know about being able to use { } to add a block of code with closed off variables etc. So thanks for the explaination and examples.

Answer (score 4):

`{}` defines a block of code. You may have such blocks anywhere in your code. It doesn't mean you have to add them after an if or something.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're allowed to open a new block in the middle of a function. This is legal:

```
void func()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    {
         Console.WriteLine("World");
    }
}
```

You can use an inner block like that to limit the scope of variables.

Your first code is an `if` statement followed by a block of code (that runs regardless of the value of the if expression).